# How to check the color of adjacent squares in a grid using tkinter in Python3

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to build the game Reversi using tkinter in python (open to pygame solutions though). I have built a functional version of the game that requires manual clicking of rectangles to flip them. The next step is to write logic that will allow a click on an empty square to both place a starting color and check the surrounding squares for the opposite color. If the opposite color is found in any direction, the code needs to continue checking in that same direction until either: an empty square is found, the edge of the board is found, or the starting color is found. In the first two circumstances, no flips occur. In the last circumstance, all the opposite color pieces in that direction are flipped.

Flipping the colors is easy to write. I am totally lost on checking the adjacent squares. Below is my most recent attempt:

```
import tkinter as tk


def create_grid(event=None):
    c.delete('all')
    w = 800
    h = 800

    # Create rectangles on whole window
    for x in range(0, w, 100):
        for y in range(0, h, 100):
            box = (x, y, x + 100, y + 100)
            b = c.create_rectangle(box, fill='green', outline='black')


def click(event, w, h):
    # Find the clicked rectangle
    current = event.widget.find_withtag("current")
    rectangle = current[0]

    # Get current fill color of rectangle
    fill = event.widget.itemcget(rectangle, "fill")
    if fill == 'green':
        fill = 'white'
    elif fill == 'white':
        fill = 'black'
    elif fill == 'black':
        fill = 'white'

    # Set new fill color
    event.widget.itemconfig(rectangle, fill=fill)
    check_directions(w, h, event)


def check_directions(w, h, event):
# **Ideally this will check each direction, but is incomplete and doesn't work yet**
    rectangle = event.widget.itemcget(rectangle)
    directions = [['N'], ['NE'], ['E'], ['SE'], ['S'], ['SW'], ['W'], ['NW']]
    for direction in directions:
        if direction == 'E':
            w += 100
            h += 0
            fill_color = event.widget.itemcget(rectangle, fill=)
            if fill_color == 'green':
                pass
            elif fill_color == 'white':
                pass
            elif fill_color == 'black':
                fill = 'white'


root = tk.Tk()

c = tk.Canvas(root, height=800, width=800, highlightthickness=0)
c.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

c.bind('<Configure>', create_grid)
c.bind('<Button-1>', click)  # Bind Left mouse button to function click()

root.mainloop()
```

I'm honestly pretty new to coding and a lot of this is cobbled together from other things that I have seen online and a couple weeks of knowledge from an online python course. If someone can help me solve how to check one square in one direction I am positive that I can solve the rest of the directions.

If destroying my current code and starting from scratch helps, I'll happily pass the detonator to learn more. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: it may need to use recursion and eventually it may need list/array to remeber which places was already visited.

Comment: hmm, those concepts are new to me, but I will look into trying that. Any idea of good reading materials to help me get a handle on it?

Answer (score 0):

In `click()` instead of one `check_directions()` I run many `check_neighbor()` with current `x, y` and different `dx, dy` (instead of `N`, `E`, etc.).

```
def click(event):

    # ... code ...

    # Current position
    x = event.x
    y = event.y

    # Check neighbors in all directions
    
    # left and right
    check_neighbor(x, y, +100, 0, fill)
    check_neighbor(x, y, -100, 0, fill)
    
    # top and bottom
    check_neighbor(x, y, 0, +100, fill)
    check_neighbor(x, y, 0, -100, fill)
    
    # diagonal 
    check_neighbor(x, y, +100, +100, fill)
    check_neighbor(x, y, -100, -100, fill)
    check_neighbor(x, y, +100, -100, fill)
    check_neighbor(x, y, -100, +100, fill)
```

This way in `check_neighbor()` I can calculate neighbor position `x+dx, y+dy` (to check color color) and I can run again `check_neighbor()` with new `x, y` but with the same `dx, dy` - so it checks the same direction.

```
def check_neighbor(x, y, dx, dy, fill):
    
    # Neighbor position
    x = x + dx
    y = y + dy
    
    # Check if it is still in window
    if 0 <= x < 800 and 0 <= y < 800:

        # Find rectangle
        rectangle = c.find_overlapping(x-1, y-1, x+1, y+1)
        
        # Get color of rectangle
        old_fill = c.itemcget(rectangle, "fill")
        
        # If not green and different then starting color then change it and go to next neighbor in the same direction
        if old_fill != 'green' and old_fill != fill:
            print('check:', x, y, old_fill)
            
            # Set new fill color
            c.itemconfig(rectangle, fill=fill)

            # Check next neighbor in the same direction
            check_neighbor(x, y, dx, dy, fill)
```

**BTW:** running `check_neighbor()` inside `check_neighbor()` is called `recursion`

---

Full code:

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def create_grid(event=None):
    c.delete('all')
    w = 800
    h = 800

    # Create rectangles on whole window
    for x in range(0, w, 100):
        for y in range(0, h, 100):
            box = (x, y, x + 100, y + 100)
            b = c.create_rectangle(box, fill='green', outline='black')


def click(event):
    # Find the clicked rectangle
    current = event.widget.find_withtag("current")
    rectangle = current[0]

    # Get current fill color of rectangle
    fill = c.itemcget(rectangle, "fill")
    
    if fill == 'green':
        fill = 'white'
    elif fill == 'white':
        fill = 'black'
    elif fill == 'black':
        fill = 'white'

    # Set new fill color
    c.itemconfig(rectangle, fill=fill)
    
    # Current position
    x = event.x
    y = event.y

    # Check neighbors in all directions
    
    # left and right
    check_neighbor(x, y, +100, 0, fill)
    check_neighbor(x, y, -100, 0, fill)
    
    # top and bottom
    check_neighbor(x, y, 0, +100, fill)
    check_neighbor(x, y, 0, -100, fill)
    
    # diagonal 
    check_neighbor(x, y, +100, +100, fill)
    check_neighbor(x, y, -100, -100, fill)
    check_neighbor(x, y, +100, -100, fill)
    check_neighbor(x, y, -100, +100, fill)


def check_neighbor(x, y, dx, dy, fill):
    
    # Neighbor position
    x = x + dx
    y = y + dy
    
    # Check if it is still in window
    if 0 <= x < 800 and 0 <= y < 800:

        # Find rectangle
        rectangle = c.find_overlapping(x-1, y-1, x+1, y+1)
        
        # Get color of rectangle
        old_fill = c.itemcget(rectangle, "fill")
        
        # If not green and different then starting color
        if old_fill != 'green' and old_fill != fill:
            print('check:', x, y, old_fill)
            
            # Set new fill color
            c.itemconfig(rectangle, fill=fill)
            
            # Check next neighbor in the same direction
            check_neighbor(x, y, dx, dy, fill)
    
# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

c = tk.Canvas(root, height=800, width=800, highlightthickness=0)
c.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

c.bind('<Configure>', create_grid)
c.bind('<Button-1>', click)  # Bind Left mouse button to function click()

root.mainloop()
```